# image slideshow with effect

Tags: web

how can i made some nice slideshow for the index.html page,
with lets say 5 images and a some effect when images are changing?
(or something simmilar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good jQuery option: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

You can [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+slideshow) it and find hundreds.